# How to Cancel any previous definition of name, either built in or provided with a ‘-D’ option in gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
#define MAGIC 5
#endif

int main(void){
        printf("\n magic is %d",MAGIC);
        return 0;
    }
```

Now i want to undef DEBUG so this program should give compilation error

```
gcc test.c -U DEBUG
```

But it does not give any error and works fine.
It means `-U` does not work.

so how can I undef any name at compile time in gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man [GCC](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) says,

```
 -D and -U options are processed in the order they are given on the command line.
```

Seems you cannot undefine a MACRO from `CLI` which is defined in program.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG

// add some new lines
#if defined(CUD_DEBUG) && defined(DEBUG)
#undef DEBUG
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
#define MAGIC 5
#endif

int main(void)
{
    printf("\n magic is %d", MAGIC);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile that by command:

```
gcc test.cc -DCUD_DEBUG
```

CUD_DEBUG means compiler undefine debug.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
#define MAGIC 5
#else
#define MAGIC 1
#endif

int main(void){
        printf("\n magic is %d",MAGIC);
        return 0;
    }
```

Now `gcc test.c -U DEBUG` will work

Comment: see my source has defined that macro and i want to undef it by command line.  If you comment out its definition in source code then there is no need to use -U at CLI.

Comment: @Mr.32: You do not need to define DEBUG macro explicitly

Comment: i know and i am not doing that. i am not sure it is defined in source or any header file so i just want to make sure about its undef so i want to undef it at CLI. so my question is if by chance in any header file if it is defined then can it be undef using CLI? I have written just sample code to explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't define DEBUG inside the program. Instead, define DEBUG while compilation as `gcc test.c -DDEBUG`.

If you want to get an error at compile time then don't define `DEBUG` at compile time as `gcc test.c`:

```
test.c: In function "main":
test.c:8: error: "MAGIC" undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:8: error: for each function it appears in.)
```